# Show that $\sqrt{6+4\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}$ is rational using the rational zeros theorem

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Let $r=\sqrt{6+4\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}$, then $r+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{6+4\sqrt{2}}$.
Squaring both sides, we get $$r^2+2r\sqrt{2}+2=6+4\sqrt{2}$$ which is the same as $r^2-4=2\sqrt{2}$.
Squaring both sides again, we get $r^4-8r^2+16=8$ or $$r^4-8r^2+8=0.\tag{$\star$}$$

The rational zeros theorem tells us that the only possible rational solutions to ($\star$) are $±1$, $±2$, $±4$, $±8$.
I do not know where to go from here. Please help me complete this proof.

Comment: $r^2+2r2\sqrt{2}+2=6+4\sqrt{2}$ is *not* the same as $r^2−4=2\sqrt{2}$. You made $r$ disappear.

Comment: Thanks.. I knew there was a mistake I wasn't catching. I'll try to solve it now.

Comment: It is essentially the same question you asked [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388206/show-that-sqrt42-sqrt3-sqrt3-is-rational-using-the-rational-zeros-the). Didn't you learn anything?

Comment: $$(2+\sqrt2)^2=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Check your second line, $r^2+2r\sqrt{2} + 2 = 6 + 4\sqrt{2} \ne r^2-4 -2\sqrt{2}$.

It *does*, however, equal $ (r-2) (r+2 \sqrt{2}+2) = 0$ which would imply that $r = 2$ or $r= -2(1+\sqrt{2})$.

Thus $2$ is the only rational root of your polynomial and $\sqrt{6+4\sqrt{2}} -\sqrt{2}= 2 $ (since $r =\sqrt{6+4\sqrt{2}} -\sqrt{2}$ and $(r-2)=\sqrt{6+4\sqrt{2}} -\sqrt{2} -2 = 0$).

Comment: Thanks! I knew there must have been a mistake i wasn't catching

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}r=\sqrt{6+4\sqrt 2}-\sqrt 2&\Rightarrow r^2+2r\sqrt 2+2=6+4\sqrt2\iff r^2-4=2\sqrt 2(2-r)\\
&\Rightarrow(r^2-4)^2=8(r-2)^2\iff(r-2)^2((r+2)^2-8)=0\\
\end{align*}
The only rational root of this polynomial is $r=2$. We have to explain why $r$ can't be one of the irrational roots $\;-2(1\pm\sqrt2)$.

Anyway it can't be the negative one: $r>0$ since $6+4\sqrt 2>2$. The other root is ${}<1$ since $(1+2)^2-8>0$. However, it's easy to see that $r>1$ since $\sqrt{6+4\sqrt 2}-\sqrt 2>\sqrt 9-\sqrt 2>3-2$.

Consequently $r$ has to be equal to $2$.

*Note:* It's a standard exercise in high school to observe that 
$$\sqrt{6+4\sqrt 2}=\sqrt{(2+\sqrt2)^2}=2+\sqrt 2,\enspace\text{whence}\quad r=2+\sqrt 2-\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: Again, plugging r into a calculator gives that r=2.

Comment: you got the wrong equation... it would be s^2-8s+8

Comment: I was correcting the mistyping…

Comment: How that, you obtain $r=2$?